# To upgrade or not to upgrade. Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, upgrade

I can't find any compelling reason why I should put in a request for my company to get me an upgrade from Visual Studio 2008 Pro to Visual Studio 2010 Anything.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Without knowing which features of Visual Studio you use, this question is quite unanswerable.

Comment: We can't find that reason, either.

Comment: James McNellis is right. For some users, Visual Studio 2010 is epic, but for others it's not so different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the compelling reason to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 from VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885955/whats-the-compelling-reason-to-upgrade-to-visual-studio-2010-from-vs2008)

Comment: VS2010 comes with a whole bag of brand new C++0x features. Oh, you don't do C++? Well, how was I to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't just about the tooling -- if you want/need the features of the .NET Framework 4.0 (runtime) and C# 4 (language -- not to mention new versions of VB.NET and all of the Dynamic Languages), you need to use VS2010.

One other consideration is whether all of your preferred add-ins have have been updated to work with VS2010, as the plugin architecture changed and vendors had to update.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple monitor support was a nice feature for me (see:http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/31/multi-monitor-support-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)

Compelling enough? Up to you.

Comment: That's one of the main reasons I want VS 2010 as my development platform at work.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a good reason to upgrade, then **don't**

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to .net 4.0, or specifically the DLR for development then go for it, if you don't require these types of features for your project, you can probably afford not to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the new features for VS 2010:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx